# Threat only unique strings - what is faster vector<std::string> or just std::string

Tags: c++, string, stl, vector, find

I read from file some strings, and I need to ignore strings that I already treated. First my thought was to create `vector<std::string>` where I will store strings and after receiving new one check if it is already in the vector. But then I though that I can do the same using just `std::string`, I think that it is faster and uses less memory, but this way isn't that obvious then using vector. Which approach is better?

Comment: I'd probably just use `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`, depending on what you're doing with them.

Comment: What approach are you talking about? **How** are going to do it using one string only? While I can come up with some viable approaches, it is important to know what you are planning to do. So, how are you planning to do it with only one string? Concatenate all existing strings?

Comment: @AndreyT yes, concatenate everything to one std::string. I'm reafing filenames, so I know that they consist only with letters, digits and a dot, every new string I can add like (pseudocode) if string::npos != allstring.find(newString ) then allstring.append('\"' + newString + '\"')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to store the strings that you have read in a `std::set<string>`.

Set lookups are generally faster than lookups in a `vector`, because sets in C++ standard library are organized as binary trees. If you put all your strings in a single long string, your search would remain linear, and you would have one more problem to solve: dealing with *word aliasing*. You wouldn't be able to concatenate strings as-is, without a separator, because you wouldn't be able to distinguish between `"abc"+"xyz"` and `"abcxyz"`